# A biased coin flipping game strategy.

Tags: probability, puzzle, binomial-distribution

I have been thinking of the following game and the best strategy to follow.

Let us assume I have a biased coin which gives head with probability $0.8$ and tails with probability $0.2$. I have been offered two options:

- Toss the coin $10$ times. If the number of heads is greater than $8$, I
  win; if it is less than $8$, I lose; if it is $8$, we play again.
- Toss the coin $20$ times. If the number of heads is greater than $16$,
  I win; if it is less than $16$, I lose; if it is $16$, we play again.

What would be the best strategy? Also, what would be the optimal number of tosses should I select have I given the option?

Comment: Have you tried computing the expected value of each strategy?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  In both cases you appear to be able to play infinitely often, so the probability that you win (eventually) is $1$.  We have no information as to what you win so I can't see why one branch should be preferred to the other.

Comment: @lulu 'What would be the best strategy?'  to play the first or the second game, why it is unclear?

Comment: Since you are sure to win either game, what difference can it make?

Comment: @lulu why am I sure to win, there is a probability to loss. i.e. if the number of heads is less than 8 in the first game, or less than 16 in the second. *I play the game only once.

Comment: Oh, you only play again if you get exactly $8$, I get it.  In that case, it is just a matter of computing the two win probabilities and comparing them.

Comment: To compute the probabilities;  start with the first one.  Let $p_i$ be the probability that you throw exactly $i$ heads.  Then you ignore $p_8$ as that just results in a replay.  Hence the probability of eventually winning along this path is $\frac {p_9+p_{10}}{1-p_8}$  And similarly for the other branch.

Comment: @lulu true, but both the win and loss probabilities are increasing in the second game. So though the probability of win is higher, in the second game, the probability of loss is also higher.

Comment: That's not possible.  The loss probability is $1$ minus the win probability.

Comment: i get the win probabilities to be $0.538401424$ and $0.526283637$ for the two games respectively.  Thus, the first game is slightly more attractive.

Comment: @lulu there is a possibility of ties (i.e. if 8 heads in the first game or 16 in the second)

Comment: No, there isn't.  You keep playing until the tie is broken.  That's why we can subtract $p_8$ from the probabilities in the first game (and $P_{16}$ in the second).

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you want to maximize your expected value. The first strategy is a random variable
$$X_1=
\begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{if } k > 8,n=10 \\
0 & \textrm{if } k < 8,n=10 \\
Y & \textrm{if } k = 8,n=10 \\
\end{cases}
$$
where $X_1 \sim Y_1$. So
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1]=(p_{9,10}+p_{10,10})+p_{8,10}\mathbb{E}[Y_1]$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1]=\frac{p_{9,10}+p_{10,10}}{1-p_{8,10}}$$
Similarly the second strategy has expected value
$$\mathbb{E}[X_2]=\frac{p_{17,20}+p_{18,20}+p_{19,20}+p_{20,20}}{1-p_{16,20}}$$
Those $p_{k,n}$ are all binomial probabilities. Turns out that $\mathbb{E}[X_1]>\mathbb{E}[X_2]$

Comment: Could you word this answer in a way that more directly relates it to the question? THX